# Null pointer in hibernate result unable to get long value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nullpointerexception, hql

I'm getting Null Pointer Exception while retrieving Primary Key or Id of an Entity in Hibernate result query. The Primary Key value is simply a long value. My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sample")
public class ccy{

@Id
@column(name = "S_ID")
private long id;

2nd varibale and so on
```

when i write hibernate query to retrieve it causes Null pointer exception, my select query is:

```
 long ID = 0;
 String HQL = "select c.id from ccy c where c.name='sowndhar' ";
 Query query = session.createQuery(HQL);
 ID = (Long)query.uniqueResult(); //getting NullPointerException in this    line
 return ID;
```

Any suggestions plz? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Obviously query must be null. So you might want to check if something with your session is wrong. Or (as I dont know about hibernate): could it be that you first have to execute your query? It seems a bit suspicious that you create a query; to then immediately try to access its result. Besides: ccy is a really bad name for a class. Should start with uppercase; and: do not abbreviate. Code exists to be read; and such abbreviations dont tell much.

Comment: Share your complete code where you are creating session and starting transaction. I doubt you have some issue with session. Another point I noticed that you are expecting Unique result from a query without a where clause. If your code worked and there are multiple records, then it will give you org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException error. Also as already stated, your naming convention is very confusing.

Comment: why should `select id from sample` return an Long, I would guess that it returns a List of Longs, or du you only have 1 entry in your database?

Comment: I think using "sample" in HQL does not work as "sample" is the table name, but HQL needs entity/class name (ccy in your case)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth How can I get list of results? Id I'm getting is an unique result. I'm sure it can't be list of results

Answer (score 1):

There are several bad Java practices in your code. By convention class names begin with a capital letter. Variable names begin with a lower case letter. Constants use all caps. [Follow the naming conventions.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

In the following code I change the type of your variable so that it allows null as a value. I also add some error handling that you will definitely want when requesting a unique result.

By the way, are you sure your `session` variable is not null? How are you getting it?

```
    Long id = null; // use the nullable Java type, not the primitive

    String HQL = "select c.id from Ccy c where c.name=:name";

    try {
        // always use parameter tokens in your query ... for security
        Query query = session.createQuery(HQL)
            .setParameter("name", name);

        id = (Long)query.uniqueResult(); 
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
        // what to do if there are multiple matches
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        // what if there is no match
    }

    return id;
```

Comment: session I'm getting it from sessionFactory

Comment: Are you sure that it is not null?

Comment: Yes that is not getting null as i'm injecting sessionFactory using spring dependency injection. Thanks for the help